# carrierwave datamapper sinatra- no files are uploaded to the server

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, carrierwave, datamapper

I have spent more than 12 hours trying to figure out what am I doing wrong. but I can't..

So I am trying to upload a picture to the server (public) using CarrierWave - Datamapper with Sinatra. The code is as follows

My model

```
require_relative "photo_uploader"

class Photo
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  belongs_to :property
  mount_uploader :source, PhotoUploader
end
```

The Uploader

```
require "carrierwave/datamapper"

class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "photos/#{model.id}/"
  end
end
```

The routes

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= 'development'

require_relative 'env_setup.rb'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions
  set :session_secret, 'something'

   #other routes

post '/properties' do
    property = Property.create(description: params[:description], price: params[:price], user_id: session[:user_id], location: params[:location])
    photo = Photo.create(title: params[:imgdescription], source: params[:pic], property_id: property.id) 

    redirect '/properties'
  end
  #other routes

  run! if app_file == $PROGRAM_NAME
end
```

The view

```
<h1> New Properties </h1>

<form action='/properties' method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='description' placeholder='Enter description'>
  <input type='number' name='price' placeholder='Enter the price'>
  <input type='text' name='location' placeholder="Property's location">
  <input type='text' name='imgdescription' placeholder='short image description'>

  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type='submit' value='Create Listing'>
</form>
```

and finally the env_setup.rb

```
require "sinatra"

require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

Bundler.require(:default, Sinatra::Application.environment)

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions           = 0666 
  config.directory_permissions = 0777  
  config.storage               = :file 

  config.cache_dir = "#{Sinatra::Application.root}/tmp"
end

if Sinatra::Application.development?
  DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
end


database_prefix = 'my_app'

DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "postgres://localhost/#{database_prefix}#{ENV['RACK_ENV']}")


require_relative './models/property.rb'
require_relative './models/user.rb'
require_relative './models/photo_uploader.rb'
require_relative './models/photo.rb'
require_relative './models/booking.rb'

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

The file name is showing up on the database but I get no photo uploaded to the server.
Any suggestions please? Also let me know if you need anything else.
Thank you in advance!